# Long working of program that count Ints

Tags: haskell

I want to write program that takes array of `Ints` and length and returns array that consist in position `i` all elements, that equals `i`, for example

```
[0,0,0,1,3,5,3,2,2,4,4,4] 6 -> [[0,0,0],[1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4,4],[5]]
[0,0,4] 7 -> [[0,0],[],[],[],[4],[],[]]
[] 3 -> [[],[],[]]
[2,2] 3 -> [[],[],[2,2]]
```

So, that's my solution

```
import Data.List
import Data.Function

f :: [Int] -> Int -> [[Int]]
f ls len = g 0 ls' [] where
    ls' = group . sort $ ls
    g :: Int -> [[Int]] -> [[Int]] -> [[Int]] 
    g val [] accum
        | len == val        = accum
        | otherwise         = g (val+1) [] (accum ++ [[]])
    g val (x:xs) accum
        | len == val        = accum
        | val == head x     = g (val+1) xs (accum ++ [x])
        | otherwise         = g (val+1) (x:xs) (accum ++ [[]])
```

But query `f [] 1000000` works really long, why?

Comment: You could write this as `\ls len -> map (\i -> filter (==i) ls) [0..len-1]`.

Comment: Beautiful solution, thanks!

Comment: @user2407038, if the list is long, that's likely to be very, very slow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `(++)` operator copies the left-hand list. For this reason, adding to the *beginning* of a list is quite fast, but adding to the *end* of a list is very slow.

In summary, avoid adding things to the *end* of a list. Try to always add to the *beginning* instead. One simple way to do that is to build the list backwards, and then reverse it at the end. A more devious trick is to use "difference lists" (Google it). Another possibility is to use `Data.Sequence` rather than a list.

Answer (score 7):

I see we're accumulating over some data structure. I think `foldMap`. I ask "Which `Monoid`"? It's some kind of lists of accumulations. Like this

```
newtype Bunch x = Bunch {bunch :: [x]}
instance Semigroup x => Monoid (Bunch x) where
  mempty = Bunch []
  mappend (Bunch xss) (Bunch yss) = Bunch (glom xss yss) where
    glom [] yss = yss
    glom xss [] = xss
    glom (xs : xss) (ys : yss) = (xs <> ys) : glom xss yss
```

Our underlying elements have some associative operator `<>`, and we can thus apply that operator pointwise to a pair of lists, just like `zipWith` does, except that when we run out of one of the lists, *we don't truncate*, rather we just take the other. Note that `Bunch` is a name I'm introducing for purposes of this answer, but it's not that unusual a thing to want. I'm sure I've used it before and will again.

If we can translate

```
0 -> Bunch [[0]]           -- single 0 in place 0
1 -> Bunch [[],[1]]        -- single 1 in place 1
2 -> Bunch [[],[],[2]]     -- single 2 in place 2
3 -> Bunch [[],[],[],[3]]  -- single 3 in place 3
...
```

and `foldMap` across the input, then we'll get the right number of each in each place. There should be no need for an upper bound on the numbers in the input to get a sensible output, as long as you are willing to interpret `[]` as "the rest is silence". Otherwise, like Procrustes, you can pad or chop to the length you need.

Note, by the way, that when `mappend`'s first argument comes from our translation, we do a bunch of `([]++)` operations, a.k.a. `id`s, then a single `([i]++)`, a.k.a. `(i:)`, so if `foldMap` is right-nested (which it is for lists), then we will always be doing cheap operations at the left end of our lists.

Now, as the question works with lists, we might want to introduce the `Bunch` structure only when it's useful. That's what `Control.Newtype` is for. We just need to tell it about `Bunch`.

```
instance Newtype (Bunch x) [x] where
  pack = Bunch
  unpack = bunch
```

And then it's

```
groupInts :: [Int] -> [[Int]]
groupInts = ala' Bunch foldMap (basis !!) where
  basis = ala' Bunch foldMap id [iterate ([]:) [], [[[i]] | i <- [0..]]]
```

What? Well, without going to town on what `ala'` is in general, its impact here is as follows:

```
ala' Bunch foldMap f = bunch . foldMap (Bunch . f)
```

meaning that, although `f` is a function to lists, we accumulate as if `f` were a function to `Bunch`es: the role of `ala'` is to insert the correct `pack` and `unpack` operations to make that just happen.

We need `(basis !!) :: Int -> [[Int]]` to be our translation. Hence `basis :: [[[Int]]]` is the list of images of our translation, computed on demand at most once each (i.e., the translation, *memoized*).

For this `basis`, observe that we need these two infinite lists

```
[ []                    [ [[0]]
, [[]]                  , [[1]]
, [[],[]]               , [[2]]
, [[],[],[]]            , [[3]]
...                     ...
```

combined `Bunch`wise. As both lists have the same length (infinity), I could also have written

```
basis = zipWith (++) (iterate ([]:) []) [[[i]] | i <- [0..]]
```

but I thought it was worth observing that this also is an example of `Bunch` structure.

Of course, it's very nice when something like `accumArray` hands you exactly the sort of accumulation you need, neatly packaging a bunch of grungy behind-the-scenes mutation. But the general recipe for an accumulation is to think "What's the `Monoid`?" and "What do I do with each element?". That's what `foldMap` asks you.

Comment: Could you start by explaining what structure you're folding over? This is not clear to me. Also, when I see `!!`, visions of quadratics start dancing in my head. Is it not problematic here for some reason?

Comment: One type of `foldMap` is `(a -> Bunch x) -> [a] -> Bunch x`. I'm folding over the input list. I'm not claiming this is the fastest solution, just that it avoids left-nesting of `++`.

Answer (score 5):

The first thing that should be noted is the most obvious way to implement this is use a data structure that allows random access, an array is an obviously choice. Note that you need to add the elements to the array multiple times and somehow "join them".

`accumArray` is perfect for this.

So we get:

```
f l i = elems $ accumArray (\l e -> e:l) [] (0,i-1) (map (\e -> (e,e)) l)
```

And we're good to go (see full code [here](http://ideone.com/ZVYyoM)).

This approach does involve converting the final array back into a list, but that step is very likely faster than say sorting the list, which often involves scanning the list at least a few times for a list of decent size.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you use `++` you have to recreate the entire list, since lists are immutable.

A simple solution would be to use `:`, but that builds a reversed list. However that can be fixed using `reverse`, which results in only building two lists (instead of 1 million in your case).

Answer (score 3):

Your concept of glomming things onto an accumulator is a very useful one, and both [MathematicalOrchid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28701797/1477667) and [Guvante](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28701722/1477667) show how you can use that concept reasonably efficiently. But in this case, there is a simpler approach that is likely also faster. You started with

```
group . sort $ ls
```

and this was a very good place to start! You get a list that's *almost* the one you want, except that you need to fill in some blanks. How can we figure those out? The simplest way, though probably not quite the most efficient, is to work with a list of all the numbers you want to count up to: `[0 .. len-1]`.

So we start with

```
f ls len = g [0 .. len-1] (group . sort $ ls)
  where
    ?
```

How do we define `g`? By pattern matching!

```
f ls len = g [0 .. len-1] (group . sort $ ls)
  where
    -- We may or may not have some lists left,
    -- but we counted as high as we decided we
    -- would
    g [] _ = []

    -- We have no lists left, so the rest of the
    -- numbers are not represented
    g ns [] = map (const []) ns

    -- This shouldn't be possible, because group
    -- doesn't make empty lists.
    g _ ([]:_) = error "group isn't working!"

    -- Finally, we have some work to do!
    g (n:ns) xls@(xl@(x:_):xls')
      | n == x    = xl : g ns xls'
      | otherwise = [] : g ns xls
```

That was nice, but making the list of numbers isn't free, so you might be wondering how you can optimize it. One method I invite you to try is using your original technique of keeping a separate counter, but following this same sort of structure.